# Allow users Create Folder inside a asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am developing a asp.net website. I want to allow users to create their own folders inside the website.

```
string pathToCreate = "~/path/sub folder";
        if (Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(pathToCreate)))
        {
            // folder exist message
        }
        else
        { //cerate folder
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(pathToCreate));
            base.OnLoad(e);
        }
```

This working when I am debugging using visual studio. But after when I host it in IIS it showing the error of Access denied to the previously specified path

```
Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sample_site\resources\users_folder' is denied.

Line 47:                 Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(pathToCreate));
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, write access is not allowed for the ASP.NET process inside the web directory.

There is an exception however. You can write to the `App_Data` directory. Just create folders inside there.

Answer (score 0):

It needs the whole path - something like `"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sample_site\resources\users_folder".`

Use `Server.MapPath("~/YourApplication/folder")  + @"\folder"` to get physical path of the folder.

**Referance:**

http://forums.asp.net/t/1622617.aspx/1

Comment: How is `'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sample_site\resources\users_folder'` not the full path?

Comment: It is full path but i think he hasnt included it in the code.

Comment: Yes 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sample_site\resources\users_folder' is my IIS localhost site path.

Answer (score 0):

Either:

1. Give write permissions to this folder for user that IIS is running under.
2. Create a new user on the server, give this user write permissions and get the website to impersonate this user by adding to the web.config:

   < identity impersonate="true" userName="username" password="password"/ >

I've always found 2. works better in our environment.